# Adding code before <body> tag in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I have bellow html code after body tag.

Now I want to move that code before body tag starts.

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#cmr"><img title="CMR &ndash; Convention Management Resources" alt="CMR &ndash; Convention Management Resources" src="http://192.168.1.145/CMSrush/wp-content/themes/cmsrush/images/cmr_logo.png"></a>
        </div>


            <a class="tar-but" id="rfp1" href="javascript:DeCryptX('tbmftAdnsvt/dpn@tvckfdu&gt;SGQ!Tvcnjttjpo')">Submit an RFP</a>          <a class="tar-but" href="#contact">Request a Demo</a>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu-top-menu-container"><div class="menu-collapser" style="display: none;"><div class="collapse-button"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></div></div><ul class="slimmenu" id="menu-top-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-317" id="menu-item-317"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-318" id="menu-item-318"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-319" id="menu-item-319"><a href="#company">Company</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-320" id="menu-item-320"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>     </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have tried to move html code before body tag but when I checked in page source it still display after body tag.

Why I don't understand.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do that at all?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, style your container properly instead.

Put this in your theme's CSS file:

```
.top-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top:0
}
```